# TensorFlow: efficient not fully connected layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a neural network that has non fully connected layers.  I've been using the functional API but the performance is terrible even on simple problems such as MNIST.  My question is one of efficiency: am I doing something poorly, is my approach incorrect (perhaps functional API is not the good way), did I miss something?

In my current code I create an input layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, concatenate

nInp=784  #sets the input size for MNIST 784
inp=Input(shape=(nInp,))
```

Then I set up a list for storing my hidden layer neurons and a list for which neurons will connect from the input to a neuron in the hidden layer.

```
n1=64  #sets the number of neurons in the hidden layer
h=[None for i in range(n1)] #initialize hidden layer storage
inpList=tf.constant([[0],[0]])
```

Now we hit the part where a **BIG SLOWDOWN** occurs.  In this for loop I cycle through each hidden layer neuron and I randomly assign connections from the input layer to the hidden neuron.

```
for j in range(n1):
    flag=0
    for i in range(nInp):
        rand=random.randint(0,1)
        if rand == 1:
            if flag==0:
                flag =1
                inpList=Lambda(lambda x:x[:,i:i+1])(inp)
            else:  
                inpList=tf.concat([inpList,Lambda(lambda x:x[:,i:i+1])(inp)],1)        
    h[j]=Dense(1, activation='relu')(inpList)
```

Then I concat my hidden layer neurons into a single layer and link it to an output layer.

```
h_layer=concatenate(h)

out=Dense(10, activation='softmax')(h_layer)

model=Model(inp,out)
```

Training on this model is **EXCRUCIATINGLY** slow.  It takes MNIST data more than half an hour per epoch to train a 784 ->64 ->10 network.  There must be a better way, because the built in Dropout layer should be performing a similar operation (but randomly setting connections every training cycle) but that executes with no discernible time penalty.

Thanks

Comment: As mentioned by you about Dropout, why don't you just try Dropout rather than the Custom Implementation.

Comment: My current goal is to train a network and look for low weights, clip those connections, then retrain the network to experiment with the impact on the network.  The long term goal is to lower parameter count by attempting to develop a method of clipping links without previous training, clip while training or clip using some probability distribution (not the trivial one I'm using in this code).  Dropout as implemented cannot achieve this.